# When to recommend deletion of low quality posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, deletion

Having recently gotten to 2,000 reputation, I have been able to review questions tagged as low quality with the possibility of recommending deletion. While certainly some questions/answers are good and definitely not worthy of deletion, a lot of questions are ambiguous as to whether they merit recommending deletion.

Most of these ambiguous questions are legitimate questions about mathematics but they are often poorly formatted (which can obviously be fixed in an edit), a clear homework question with none of the OP's thoughts, attempted solutions, or other context, or are lack important details like notations (which may or may not have been clarified in the comments.) Answers can be similarly hard to classify, with answers that do have valuable insights to the OP but which are incomplete.

I searched around the help center but there seemed to be nothing of use as to when to recommend deletion. Could there be a section of the help center added to help establish guidelines about when to recommend deletion on posts, perhaps including "worked examples" of when to and when not to recommend deletion?

Also, presumably the mechanism of downvoting is the primary way on this site of signaling the quality of content. In which contexts is deletion seen as necessary rather than simply downvoting? Is recommending deletion in the case of low quality seen as a subjective measure or is there an objective standard?

Comment: I would suggest recommending to delete or close anything that seems like it is not a positive addition to the site. These days there are a huge number of garbage questions (PSQs) that this site would be much better off without.

Comment: You might have a look at some of the questions listed under Related on this page to see what's been said before about deletion decisions.

Comment: Also, you could look at some of the 150 meta questions tagged "deletion", https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion?sort=active&pageSize=50

Comment: You can find some network-wide recommendations on meta.SE: [When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842) (It is about voting to delete, not about recommending deletion in the review queue, but these two actions actually lead to rather similar final effect. Differences are explained here: [The difference between “Delete” and “Recommend Deletion”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25229))

Comment: I will also add a link to an on-going discussion about deleting answers: [Should we vote to delete wrong answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27423) This older question seems related, too: [Deleting Wrong Answers in “Low Quality” Queue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16298).